# ObtaI n url of page which fired ajax request in ajax view

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, xmlhttprequest

I have some page `/page/< some_id >/`.
On this page I have form which are sent to some other url `/ajaxreq/`.
Is it possible to read `/page/< some_id >/` from request object in `/ajaxreq/` view?

PS: I know, this is a design issue and there are many other ways to solve it, but it is interesting is such approach possible or not? It will be very useful and graceful in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` in the view and extract the info from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with JS It should be something like this:

```
var link = [];
var url = window.location.pathname;
link = url.split('/');

var some_id = link[link.length-1];
```

Comment: Yes, but I need it on server side. In this case I need add one more parameter to /ajaxreq/, and change code of my ajax request, e.g. url: '/ajaxreq/'+some_id+'/'.